# Implement Color wheel in UPBGE

Tags: game-engine, eevee-render-engine, color

I am facing an issue in UPBGE.
I started using this version of blender few weeks ago to create different scenes to show our clients different products we designed.
Like a demonstrator.

I would like to implement a Color Wheel for the client to choose the product color live.

I would like to have such a wheel in game mode, not in the shader editor. That when you are in game, you choose the product color while playing.

Something looking like that :
[image: eColorWheeld]

I would like the user to be able to drag a cursor on the wheel and it would change my diffuse color in my material.

I tried to research some tutorials, but I could find anything working so far.

Any ideas to achieve something like that ?
Or any tutorial to recommend ?

Cheers !

Comment: Blender already has color wheels that pop up when you edit color inputs. If they are not good for your purpose, you should edit the question and explain why and what exact functionality you need instead. Provide more context and screenshots as well if possible so people understand your situation.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer, I think I explained wrong, I would like to have such a wheel in game mode, not in the shader editor.
That when you are in game, you choose the product color while playing.
Cheers

Comment: Your questions is at least about : display color wheel + display pointer + display pointed color + move pointer when clicked + link wheel to some code + hide color wheel. If you need help for all of it, then you probably have to take it step-by-step.

Comment: I understood that you meant a color wheel in game mode, but regular Blender has no game mode, and this site is about helping with problems in the official Blender software.